# How to set center component on a fixed position in Java using GridLayout?

Tags: java, center, fixed, grid-layout

I have this Gridlayout in Java.

It has 3 columns.
The left and right columns contain an image and the center column contains the data.

Since Im not very used to using layoutmanagers I need to ask it over here.

How can I set the left and right columns to a variable width and the center layout to a fixed with. So that the left and right columns will crop  but the center column stays intact and in the center of the screen?

And is this even possible with a GridLayout?

Answer (score 2):

A `GridLayout` is too rigid for your application: you cannot tell it to treat some rows or columns different than others. Perhaps you should have a look at `GridBagLayout`. There you can use `weight` settings to distribute additional space to the image parts, have them `fill` the additional space assigned to them, and have the central part at its preferred size. In case preferred size isn't the size you want, you might have to wrap that component into some component for which you can set the preferred size.